# Compare dates in 2 date time fields

Tags: apex

I just want to compare these two date/time fields but the time is causing issues. How to remove the time or ignore it and compare them like if (prevStartDate == currStartDate)

Thanks

```
Date prevStartDate = 2016-05-29 14:02:00;
Date currStartDate = 2016-05-29 16:02:00;
```

Comment: Are the values of dates you're looking at stored in GMT but were created from different locations or are they Date-Times that you need to get the Date Values of? It appears to me to be the latter. Note that the dates are the same, only the times are different in the examples you're showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to compare Date-Times as Dates, just use `prevStartDat.Date()` and `currStartDate.Date()` to convert them to Date values. See the [date-time class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_date) for more.

Answer (score 2):

crmprogdev is correct. Here's an example.

```
// Create dummy date times
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime previousDate = currentDate.addDays(-1);
// Set date times to dates
currentDate = currentDate.Date();
previousDate = previousDate.Date();
System.debug('Current Date: ' + currentDate);
System.debug('Previous Date: ' + previousDate);
System.debug(previousDate < currentDate);
```